# how to prevent git from using logged in username

Tags: bash, git

I would like to make it possible for any user to clone a repository *without having to specify the username in the clone command*.

For example, say my git username is **john.doe** (e.g. customer requirement) but the local account I am logged into on my PC is **j.doe** (e.g. company requirement), git will attempt to use *j.doe* to clone the repository.

This is quite a subtle but significant different so I've used the following 2 examples to illustrate:

#### 1. Cloning with anonymous syntax:

If I do the following:

```
j.doe~
$ git clone https://mygit.repo.url/somerepository.git
```

... git assumes **without asking** that the remote username is the same as the username of the local account (i.e. *j.doe*) and attempts to clone as follows :

```
Cloning into somerepository
j.doe@mygit.repo.url's password:
```

but, in this case, *j.doe* is not an account on the remote repository.

#### 2. Cloning with explicit username:

The usual workaround is to specify the remote username as follows:

```
j.doe~
$ git clone https://john.doe@mygit.repo.url/somerepository.git
```

This succeeds but requires that every user uses a different clone command.

#### Why do I care?

There are several cases where the anonymous syntax would be more suitable, for example:

1. It is more portable to automate - no need to write OS or language specific input statements to grab the username.
2. It is more consistent for the user. The user/password request will always look the same.
3. It makes it easier to write clear and consistent installation instructions. The user may copy and paste.
4. Prevents having to write a different wrapper for every scripting language and OS that tries to automate the procedure.
5. When checking out a repository that relies on git submodules the .gitmodules files must first be edited to include the username if the logged in user is not the same as the git user. This is very inconvenient in the case of multiple users.

#### Case in point.

I know this functionality is possible because github use it. For example, if you clone a repository on github using the *anonymous syntax* you will see something like the following:

```
j.doe~
$ git clone https://github.com/dbostock/d3.git
Cloning into 'd3'...
Username for 'https://github.com':
```

Pretty nice! Using any shell, any OS, any scripting language, I can identify, authenticate and clone my repository.

So in the end, my question boils down to : **How do github do this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I read the answer seems to be the protocol used to clone the repository. According to [this git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols), in the section titled ***The SSH protocol*** it says:

> You can also not specify a user, and Git assumes the user you’re currently logged in as.

Alternative protocols include:

- **https** - used by github and which does allow you to specify a user,
- **local** - which does not require authentication,
- **git** - does not mention ssh issue but I have yet to check.

Comment: I've accepted my own answer to close the issue (and I'm pretty sure it's correct!).

Answer (score 1):

Root can use `sudo` just like any other user can. Either that, or just change ownership of the files after the clone operation.

> Is there a way, either from the client or server, to configure a git
>   repository so that it always asks for the username?

Git will use the username either as specified in ~/.git/config or as specified in your repository URL. Keep in mind, though, that this is the **remote system** username, not the local username, so it will not affect ownership at all.

The solution here is to use `sudo` for your git clone operation.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately sudo doesn't help because the script does not know in advance which git username will be running the script. There is no crossover between the local usernames and the git usernames. I would like it to ask for a username (just like github does). The user cannot clone as root because they don't have such access to the git repo. There is no user configured in .git/config ... therefore it uses the logged in user. That's the behaviour I would like to change.

Comment: You are confusing "git username" with local usernames. The username that github is asking for is a **remote username**, on their system, not on yours. You have two users to consider. 1) Which local system user is running the clone and 2) The user on the remote system that has access to the git repo. These can be changed independently. Your local user can be controlled via `sudo`, and the remote user, well, you should be able to sort that out.

Comment: I am not confusing them. I want to clone using remote user x, y or z. I don't know which one will do the checkout but the script is run as root. The local user is kiosk and no other accounts are allowed. Instead of trying to clone using `git clone ssh://root@gitrepo/repo.git` I want git to ask me which username to use. If I use sudo git will try `git clone ssh://kiosk@gitrepo/repo.git` which is also not what I want. I just want git to ask me for the username just like github does.

Comment: So you're running this script interactively? If so, then just write a bottle bash wrapper that asks for the desired username and then uses that in the clone operation.

Comment: That is as far as I've got. However, I would like to be able to use a more general, platform independent solution. I see that it is possible to do (e.g. github) but I could not figure out how they do it so I thought I would ask here.